# Calculate the number of possible passwords

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know how many possible 8 length passwords can be generated with 72 distinct characters: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()`

No, other limitations, the characters can definitely repeat though.

Thanks.

Comment: I am confused by your query.  Wouldn't the answer just be $(72)^8.$

Comment: Oh yes, I think you are right

Comment: If the password has only 1 character, there are 72 choices.  If 2 characters, there are $72 \times 72$ choices.  And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

So we have $8$ characters, and $72$ options for each character, so we have
$$ 72\cdot 72 \cdot 72 \cdot 72 \cdot \ldots = \boldsymbol{72^8}$$

passwords.

Answer (score 1):

The number of possibilities for each password character is $72$. There are $8$ such characters in the password. Hence total number of possibilities is given by
$$N = 72\times 72\times 72\times 72\times 72\times 72\times 72=72^8$$